# Convert stdClass object to PDO object

Tags: php, soap, pdo, wsdl

I am doing a database connection through web services using PHP's PDO. On returning the PDO object through SOAP I get the SOAP response as

```
<value xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Struct"/>
```

And on dumping the value I get

```
object(stdClass)#4 (0) { }
```

How do I convert this object of stdClass to a PDO object as I need to maintain the object throughout my application for executing queries? Or should I not use services at all for the database connection?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to use a web service to fulfill all the database related operations (including connection and executing queries). For connecting and querying I am using PDO. Now whenever I need to execute a query I need the PDO connection object. I cannot afford to connect to the database everytime I need to execute a query. So I need the PDO connection object as kind of global throughout my app. But after the connection SOAP sends it back as stdClass which is of no use to me as I cant run PDO statements using the stdClass object....

Comment: So .. the website sends you connection details like hostname, database, username, password and queries to perform, and then that must be executed?  Or, you are trying to create a global connection object that you can use to query your database?

Comment: Exactly!! A global connection object with which I can query my database.

Comment: Ahh .. so soap has nothing to do with that. I'll see if I can get a example together for you.

Comment: I am using SOAP and WSDL to send and receive the requests and responses. (Like send the database credentials using SOAP and receive the connection object using SOAP).

Comment: Can you show how the soap server sends credentials?

Comment: $USER_CREDENTIALS = $soapClient->CONNECT($DSN, $USER, $PASSWORD). The CONNECT function connects to the database with the PDO using ($DSN, $USER, $PASSWORD).